# How can I get the last 12 months from the current date PLUS extra days till 1st of the last month retrieved

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Getting the last 12 months from a specific date is easy and can be retrieved by the following command in SQL-server. Its answer is 2014-08-17.

```
select Dateadd(Month, -12, '2015-08-17')
```

What I want is to get the last 12 months but ending at 2014-08-**01** (in the above case) instead of any where in the middle of the month.

Comment: Your example is a `select`.  This does not filter any data.  Can you fix the question so it is more clear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `DATEADD` and `DATEDIFF`:

```
DECLARE @ThisDate DATE = '20150817'
SELECT DATEADD(YEAR, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '19000101', @ThisDate), '19000101'))
```

For more common date routines, see this [article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/lynnpettis/2009/03/25/some-common-date-routines/) by Lynn Pettis.

---

To use in your `WHERE` clause:

```
DECLARE @ThisDate DATE = '20150817'
SELECT *
FROM <your_table>
WHERE
    <date_column> >= DATEADD(YEAR, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '19000101', @ThisDate), '19000101'))
```

Comment: I am newbie, how can I add your answer in my part of the query given below
DateADD(Month, 12, Dateadd(Month, -12, @ForLastupDate))

Comment: I got it Select DateADD(Month, 12, DATEADD(YEAR, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '19000101', '2015-08-17'), '19000101')))

Answer (score 14):

```
SELECT dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,getdate())-12,0)
```

Result is

```
-----------------------
2014-08-01 00:00:00.000
```

So the where clause should be

```
WHERE datecol >=dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,getdate())-12,0)
```

to get all data starting from jan 01 of last year's same month

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the records since the first day of the current month last year, then you can use:

```
where <somedate> >= dateadd(day, 1 - day(dateadd(month, -12, getdate()),
                            dateadd(month, -12, getdate()))
```

For all days *except* Feb 29th, you can use the simpler:

```
where <somedate> >= dateadd(day, 1 - day(getdate()),
                            dateadd(month, -12, getdate))
```