# How can I get the last 12 weeks from the current date PLUS extra days till the start of the week if the week start at Sunday

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Getting the last 12 weeks from a specific date is easy and can be retrieved by the following command in SQL-server. Its answer is 2014-08-17.

```
select Dateadd(Week, -12, '2015-08-17')
```

What I want is to get the last 12 weeks but ending at the end of week. I dont want to see last week of 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 days. Please help.

Comment: So you want the last *full* 12 weeks? Sunday to Saturday?

Comment: Please give an example of your desired results.   The question is not clear.

Comment: yes you are right, from a specific date. say 2015-08-16

Comment: It is similar to my this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32049478/how-can-i-get-the-last-12-months-from-the-current-date-plus-extra-days-till-1st]

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is to break it down to pieces:

First, [Find the date of the last Sunday](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5925176/3094533) (thanks to [Andriy M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/297408/andriy-m))

Then all you have to do is use `DateAdd(week, -12, @LastSunday)`.

Here is the full script:

```
DECLARE @Date datetime = GETDATE(),
        @LastSunday datetime,
        @TargetDate datetime


SET @LastSunday = DATEADD(day,
                          -1 - (DATEPART(dw, @Date) + @@DATEFIRST - 2) % 7,
                          @Date
                          )

SET @TargetDate = DATEADD(week, -12, @LastSunday)
```

[Play with it your self in this sql fiddle..](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/3664)

Comment: One problem is that I also want to show data of the current week. Any idea?

Comment: why is that a problem? just get the data between `@TargetDate` (12 weeks ago) and `@NextSaturday` (If you already know how to get last Sunday, surly you can figure out how to get next Saturday...)